# How do I groupby hours of day to find out the highest order?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a beginner user of python and pandas. I'm trying to answer the question of Do people order different foods at different times of day? So I thought that grouping by hours and pick the highest number of department orders can answer the question. The data set looks life below.

I've tried groupby[["order_hour","department"]] but wasn't correct answer

```
order_hour_of_day   department  num_orders_hour
0   alcohol 33
1   alcohol 32
2   alcohol 5
3   alcohol 3
4   alcohol 2
5   alcohol 12
6   alcohol 34
7   alcohol 92
8   alcohol 161
9   alcohol 343
10  alcohol 409
11  alcohol 456
12  alcohol 494
13  alcohol 520
14  alcohol 518
15  alcohol 620
16  alcohol 528
17  alcohol 443
18  alcohol 352
19  alcohol 220
20  alcohol 149
21  alcohol 85
22  alcohol 46
23  alcohol 41
...
0   babies  70
1   babies  70
2   babies  49
3   babies  25
4   babies  22
5   babies  38
6   babies  202
7   babies  530
8   babies  948
9   babies  1257
10  babies  1153
11  babies  1086
12  babies  958
13  babies  1130
14  babies  1191
15  babies  1184
16  babies  1145
17  babies  858
18  babies  710
19  babies  594
20  babies  642
21  babies  489
22  babies  395
23  babies  195
```

I expet to have answer like below

```
order_hour_of_day   department  num_orders_hour tot_orders_dept
0   alcohol 533 5598
1   snacks 532  5598
2   snacks 555  5598
3   snacks 523  5598
4   beverages 512   5598
5   beverages 512   5598
6   breakfast 534   5598
7   bakery 492  5598
8   breakfast 661   5598
...
21  other 865   5598
22  other 646   5598
23  alcohol 41  5598
```

Comment: we need a example of your dataframe and your expected out for the example

Comment: what is `tot_orders_dept`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [GroupBy.first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df.sort_values('num_orders_hour',ascending=False).groupby('order_hour_of_day').first()
```